# Triple des decryption function not working

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, 3des, php-openssl

So i've been working at this function and i'm not sure what's wrong.

I get encrypted data and key:

```
$key = 'aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd';
$data = 'b5057bbc04b842a96144a0f617f2820e';
```

I've gone and converted them into binary:

```
$key = pack('H*',$key);
$data = pack('H*',$data);
```

And ran the decryption function:

```
echo bin2hex(mcrypt_decrypt(Mcrypt_3des, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```

However what I get returned is this : `e2119b734b5050e3fa8717ee17f3a548`

But if I run the same decryption on http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/
or http://www.emvlab.org/descalc/?key=aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd&iv=0000000000000000&input=b5057bbc04b842a96144a0f617f2820e&mode=ecb&action=Decrypt&output=54657374313233313233000000000000

It actually decrpyts to `54 65 73 74 31 32 33 31 32 33 00 00 00 00 00 00`

which is actually `Test123123`

Any suggestions of what could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

I have tried switching to `openssl_decrypt`

However I keep getting a false returned.

Code:

```
$result = openssl_decrypt($data,'des-ede3', $key);
result = bool(false)
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, [mcrypt is a dead project](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt) and might be removed from a future version of PHP

Comment: @Machavity Good to know, would there be any newer functions that I could have used instead?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/openssl_decrypt

Comment: Where do people keep getting this mcrypt code from?

Comment: @LukePark on this website

Comment: Do you see the countless warnings underneath that say not to use it? I feel like no one ever does!

Comment: @LukePark I do see the warning however the hardware that I am working with only does that.

Comment: I'm fairly sure your hardware will support the equivalent OpenSSL functions.

Comment: @LukePark As you can see on the question I have tried that too.

Comment: @LukePark And your responses have not helped with the question.

Comment: Well don't get bitter.  It's likely a padding problem.  Mcrypt doesn't support pkcs7 padding.  Another reason to use OpenSSL.  Also DES should not be used, it's 2016.  This isn't for production right?

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working using open SSLs decryption function:

```
$key = 'aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd';
$key = pack('H*',$key);

// DATA
$data = 'b5057bbc04b842a96144a0f617f2820e';
$data = pack('H'.strlen($key),$data);

// DECRYPT OPEN SSL
$result = openssl_decrypt($data,'des-ede', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
```